# Laravel 4.2 Migrate

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unique('username', 10);
        $table->unique('email', 20);
        $table->unique('phone', 16);
        $table->string('password', 100);
        $table->string('password_temp', 100);
        $table->string('operation_password', 100);
        $table->string('operation_password_temp', 100);
        $table->integer('groupe_id', 1);
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

не пойму из за чего эта ошибка

> Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition;
>   there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Так у вас `id` не объявлен как ключ, на это и ругается.

Comment: ну в доках вроде бы так, не подскажите как правильно?

Comment: как правильно не знаю - с ним не знаком, но в доках есть следующий пример: `$table->primary('id');` Может быть это именно то, что требуется

Comment: теперь Key column 'id' doesn't exist in table)

Comment: Я надеюсь вы весь свой прошлый код не трогали? Не надо было удалять `$table->increments('id');`, надо было просто добавить `$table->primary('id');` Т.е. первой строкой вы создали поле `id`, а последней строкой сделали его `primary key`.

Comment: да так и сделал но теперь Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: А, все, [нашел](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_integer). В `$table->integer('groupe_id', 1);` второй параметр означает `autoIncrement ` Т.е. вы создаете два поля с автоинкрементом, а разрешено только одно. Зачем вам `1` в `groupe_id`? И тогда не знаю нужна ли строчка `$table->primary('id');` или и без нее нормально отработает. Попробуйте ее сначала убрать, а если будет та же ошибка, тогда верните ее.

Comment: да, все, спасибо огромное за вашу помощь !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я постараюсь объяснить в чем проблема.

Проблема в том, что поле с автоинкрементом в таблице может быть только 1:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table) {

        $table->increments('id'); // Первое поле с автоинкрементом
        /* ... */
        $table->integer('groupe_id', 1); // Второе поле с автоинкрементом
        /* ... */

    });
}
```

Вы, видимо, хотели установить значение по умолчанию, а с тем синтаксисом, который у вас был, вы включали автоинкремент.

[Исходный код (нужная строчка подсвечена)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L443)

Выдержка:

```
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
{
    return $this->addColumn('integer', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
}
```

Таким образом, вторым параметром вы включали автоинкремент, а не устанавливали значение по умолчанию.

Чтобы реализовать нужную вам задачу, нужно было делать так:

```
/* Целочисленное поле типа TINYINT со значением 1 по умолчанию */
$table->tinyInteger('groupe_id')->default(1);
```

[Типы полей в Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns)

Comment: да, спасибо я уже понял, но $table->integer('groupe_id')->default(1); мня не устраивает так как длина 11 получается, а надо 1, просто сделал $table->string('groupe_id', 1)->default(1);
спасибо еще раз за ваше разъяснения буду иметь введу!

Comment: Вы не поняли. Таким образом вы не задаете длину для integer. Вы вообще не можете задать конкретную длину для поля типа integer с помощью laravel. Если вам нужно целочисленное поле с длиной 1, то используйте тип `tinyInteger`.   
Вот так: `$table->tinyInteger('groupe_id')->default(1);`

Comment: ясно, надо просто запомнить все) информации много сейчас идет)

Answer (score 0):

решилось так

```
     Schema::create('users', function($table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 10)->unique();
        $table->string('email', 20)->unique();
        $table->string('phone', 16)->unique();
        $table->string('password', 100);
        $table->string('password_temp', 100);
        $table->string('operation_password', 100);
        $table->string('operation_password_temp', 100);
        $table->string('groupe_id', 1)->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```